# Dokku installation fails

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dokku

I'm building provisioning ansible script. I often execute it for debug purpose during development. I use digital ocean ubuntu 14 droplet. For a long time everything was ok, but few days ago the same code stopped working (every execution is on a fresh droplet)

I have an error installing Dokku 0.4.3

```
--> Installing dokku
OK
deb https://packagecloud.io/dokku/dokku/ubuntu/ trusty main
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dokku : Depends: docker-engine but it is not installable or
                  docker-engine-cs but it is not installable or
                  lxc-docker but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I use this command for installation:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.github.com/progrium/dokku/v0.4.3/bootstrap.sh | sudo DOKKU_TAG=v0.4.3 bash
```

Do anybody know how to solve this issue? Thank's

Comment: Back in march, the package name for docker changed to: docker-ce (community addition), or docker-ee (enterprise edition). I have not played with dokku in a while, so I don't know if it is just a case of the dokku package needing to be updated to reflect the new upstream package names?

Comment: Could you include the relevant bits of your ansible script so someone could try to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The version of Dokku wildly out of date (released back in October 2015). See their home pagehttp://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/ for an updated installation URL.

I am guessing whatever playbook you are using (or creating) just needed to be updated. The Dokku installation script at version 0.4.3 probably assumes the Docker package name is `docker-engine`. The newer Docker package names for the Dokku installation were introduced around 0.8: https://github.com/dokku/dokku/commit/1e387b3b420a49ff87d16265a30efade2f1a0dbf.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading dokku to 0.9 issue was sovled